I get different results when I scan from a barcode reader with a different language
We produce qr barcode labels in the program we use in our company. The data is pulled from the sql database through the table.
Our problem
We have 2 types of readers. When we read from one of them, the data and the characters in the content come normally, but when we read from the other, the special characters come differently. In fact, the source of the end is due to the fact that the language of the reader is English and the language cannot be changed to Turkish. By writing the code I want, no matter which reader I read from, I can get proper data in both.
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  Barcode2D1.text:=<QBaslik."UREBILBASLIK_STOKNO">+' '+<QBaslik."UREBILBASLIK_LOTNO"> +' '+formatfloat('###,##0.00',<QBaslik."UREBILBASLIK_MIKTAR">);
end;

begin

end.

enter image description here
enter image description here
By writing the code I want, no matter which reader I read from, I can get proper data in both.

Please post model numbers of the readers.  What coding scheme are using on the readers

First of all, it seems reasonable to me that an English reader will not do Turkish.
Assuming that you are not explaining it correctly, you need to make sure that both readers have the same default coding scheme.  This is not the language rather it's the pattern encoded with stripes.
